# Modify a cell content of a specific row right after creating the corresponding column into a SelectionChanged method

Tags: c#, wpf

I Have a little issue with my datagrid trying to populate cell content on live during program execution. I Have actually a datagrid with 2 columns and one row containing an object series. When a value of the combobox is selected, I programmatically add a new column to the row and i try to populate the cell content of this column on the respective row.

my xaml:

```
<Label Content="Series" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGrid Name="dataSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding series}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Season">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="seasonsNumber" ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}" SelectedValuePath="Number" DisplayMemberPath="Number"  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and the method reached on the SelectionChanged event:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*var content = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString();*/
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow) dataSeries.ContainerFromElement(comboBox);
        Serie selectedSerie = (Serie) dataSeries.Items[row.GetIndex()];

        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = "Episodes",
            Binding = new Binding()
        };
        dataSeries.Columns.Add(column);

        Season seasonSelected = selectedSerie.Seasons.Find(season => season.Number.ToString() == comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());


        var cell = (DataGridCell) dataSeries.Columns[dataSeries.Columns.IndexOf(column)].GetCellContent(row);
        (cell.Content as TextBlock).Text = "";
        foreach (Episode episode in seasonSelected.Episodes)
        {
            if ((cell.Content as TextBlock).Text == "")
            {
                (cell.Content as TextBlock).Text = episode.Title;
            }
            else
            {
                (cell.Content as TextBlock).Text = "-" + episode.Title;
            }
        }
    }
```

The corresponding object models:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Season")]
public class Season
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Episode", Type=typeof(Episode))]
    public List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}

public class Episode : VideoDataBaseItem
{
}

public abstract class VideoDataBaseItem
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

What i am trying to do is when my ComboBox selection is changed, create the column Episodes then fill the cell of this column at the corresponding row with the values of the episodes of the current Serie.

I'm actually having issue with a System.NullReferenceException, like if the cell wasn't instanciated when i'm trying in the foreach to populate the cell and I found no other way than the CellContent method to recover the cell object.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit:

I tried to did what you said to me, i'm still facing issues at the Visibility binding:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColumnVisibility x:Key="ColumnVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Episodes" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=dataSeries, Path=seasonsNumber.SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ColumnVisibility}}" Binding="{Binding ElementName=seasonsNumber, Path=SelectedItem.Episodes, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

the MainWindow c# file added content:

```
public class ColumnVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int param = (int)parameter;
        int val = (int)value;

        return ((param & val) != 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((Visibility)value)
        {
            case Visibility.Collapsed:
            case Visibility.Hidden:
                return false;
            case Visibility.Visible:
                return true;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the Converter is never reached actually.

Comment: You are really swimming upstream here.  This is not the MVVM way of doing things.  I can probably get your code working but neither one of us would be proud of it.  Do this:  add the episodes column to the XAML.  Bind the visibility of the column to the selected value such that it is invisible when no series is selected.  Bind the episode column to the  series selected i the combo box.  Use a data converter to find and format the episodes for the series.  If I had more time I would write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: i edited the topic with the new elements trying to follow your instructions.